Keyboard stops working Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Many older posts (some 10 years) with same issue but not seeing new ones.
New install.  Works for a short time after boot then nothing.  Reboot nets the same result.  Keyboard functions normal on Mint system, swapping keyboards shows the issue with Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS.  Have read older posts and checked some on this system not sure what the deal is, especially when all good after boot, for the short while.  Thanks.

Does journalctl -b list anything at the time when the problem occurs?

Of course, also check sudo dmesg -T to see if there's any indication or if maybe the USB port is going to sleep for power saving mode or something (this is more common on laptops but still possible).
